# Why the url to remove the registration type is always the same?

Tags: laravel

I have a button to remove "Remove registration type" to remove a registration type. When this button is clicked it shows a modal for the user to confirm that he wants to remove the registration type.

But its not working properly, for example for the conference in question there are 2 registration types (general and plus) and when the user clicks in the "Remove regisstration type" button either for the registration type "general" or "plus" the modal appear and the link for "yes" button is always the same, with the same registration type id, like "https://proj.test/conference/destroy/1/rtypes".

But it should appear "https://proj.test/conference/destroy/1/rtypes" in the modal relative to the registration type "general" and "https://proj.test/conference/destroy/2/rtypes" in the modal relative to the registration type "plus".

Do you know where is the issue?

```
<div class="form-group col col-lg-6">
<label for="registration_types">Registration types</label>
    <div class="hide-first">
        @foreach($registrationType as $rtype)
            <div class="form-check">
            <input {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $rtype->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            <span>{{$rtype->name}} </span><span><a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light-gray"
            data-target="#removeRtype">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove registration type</a></span>
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="removeRtype" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <p>Do you want to remove the registration type?</p>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="cancel_remove" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary ml-2" id="confirm_remove" href="{{route('rtype.remove', ['rtypeID' => $rtype->id])}}">Yes</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: U used same ID on all modal. Try changin it. Example add rtype after that

Comment: Thanks, it works like that.